# How to split two sticked words with regex, one ALL CAPS and the other one begins with a capital letter

Tags: c#, regex

Below are some input examples:

- UIHint ==> UI + Hint
- RSSReader ==> RSS + Reader
- IPAddress ==> IP + Address

I made something like this

([A-Z]+)(([A-Z])([a-z]+))

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "IPAddress";
        var result = Regex.Matches(input, "([A-Z]+)(([A-Z])([a-z]+))");
        foreach (Match match in result)
        {
            foreach (var item in match.Groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the output:

```
IPAddress
IP
Address
A
ddress
```

But by using it, Match Groups contains also "A" and "dress" for "IPAddress" for example that I don't want them.

I only want the main input (IPAddress), "Address" and "IP" in the match group.

So How should I change the regex pattern?

Comment: Environment? Language?

Comment: Does it necessary?  You can assume c# as the language. @ClasG

Comment: @RezaAhmadi: Your [regex works](https://regex101.com/r/oU4cI0/1). `IPAddress` should get matched. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: @rock321987 Quote: `IPAddress ==> IP + Address`  - where do you get that it shouldn't match? It *shouldn't* match "Adress" if I get OP correctly.

Comment: By my own regex IPAddress matches but "A" and "dress" match also, I just want IP and Address. @ClasG you was right. thank you.

Comment: @RezaAhmadi: No, they [do not match](https://regex101.com/r/hX4iQ6/1).

Comment: Specifying the language is almost certainly necessary. (Some regex features may vary) People shouldn't need to guess stuff about your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
([A-Z]+)([A-Z]\w*)
```

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zT6xO1/2).

It'll give you the two parts in two capture groups.

**Edit:** Fixed faulty match of `Adress`.

Comment: I don't want $3 or $4 substitution @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @RezaAhmadi: No idea what you want to say. If you do not need the additional capture groups, why introduce them at all? However, as I say, your initial regex is working. **Unless** you want to also match words in all languages. The current one only matches ASCII letters.